# How do I create a print function in R?

Tags: r, function, printing

The following is my data,

```
Number Score
0.00 4.00
0.31 2.07
0.63 2.15
0.94 3.08
1.26 4.09
1.57 2.39
1.88 1.96
2.20 3.72
```

I want to create a function that on output gives me,

```
Scores by Number (z = 8)

Number Score
0.00 4.00
0.31 2.07
0.63 2.15
0.94 3.08
1.26 4.09

5 more rows
```

I know that the skeleton of the function should look something like this, but I've never dealt with also providing words/phrases on output.

```
print <- function(x, ...)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste`, `cat`, `print` to print the output

```
print_new <- function(dat) {
      nr <- nrow(dat)
      n <- 5
      n1 <- nr - n
      cat(sprintf("Scores by Number (z = %d)", nr), "\n")
      cat('', '\n')
      print(head(dat, n))
      cat('', '\n')
      cat(sprintf('%d more rows', n1))




  }

print_new(df1)
#Scores by Number (z = 8) 

#  Number Score
#1   0.00  4.00
#2   0.31  2.07
#3   0.63  2.15
#4   0.94  3.08
#5   1.26  4.09

#3 more rows
```